# 405 trying to post to default page in IIS6

Tags: iis-6

I've got a weird problem in IIS6, I expect it's something silly (I'm a bit rusty on the IIS front).

I can post to my default page fine if I include it in the url (`http://localhost/wiki/wiki.asp?pg=Home`), but if I post without (`http://localhost/wiki/?pg=Home`) I get a 405.

If I do a `get` with that second URL, it works ok.

I don't think it's an ASP error, because I've got 'Send detailed error message to client' selected.

(Note: this is IIS on a workstation)

Comment: Same here: HTTP 405 - Resource not allowed. Log file shows: 19:22:17 127.0.0.1 POST /Saml/ 405

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs with a post to a URL that doesn't have an exception, in IIS 5.1 (workstation).  Here are more details and the solution: http://www.somacon.com/p126.php.

According to this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216493), that default setting was fixed in IIS6, which is why you see it on the workstation only.

Comment: Scott, I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt on this one. I won't have time in the next two days to check! Happy Christmas...

Comment: Thanks Benjol. I believe and hope that it's what you're looking for.  Merry Christmas!